# SQL Simple ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I'm new to SQL and I don't think this question should be hard to answer. I have a high-score table for a game that contains the columns name, score, and rank. I want to know how I can order the table by descending order each time a new score is added so the table can always stay ordered by score.

I know this is the wrong way of doing this, but I hope this makes my point kind of clearer.

```
UPDATE `HSTable`.`Highscores` ORDER BY `Highscores`.`score` DESC;
```

What is the correct way of approaching this?

One more thing, is there a way I can set it so that the ranking value always stays where it's suppose to be from the SQL, for example, 1st place is always at the top regardless the score?

Comment: A SQL database doesn't **store** its data in a particular order, so you **cannot** re-order it - you have to define the `ORDER BY` when you do a `SELECT` to get the order you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generally we use order by while fetching data from table

so we use

```
SELECT * FROM `HSTable` ORDER BY `score` DESC
```

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1):

Use a ranking function like RANK or DENSE_RANK to rank the results. For better performance you can add a clustered index that starts with score descending.

Answer (score 0):

You can get ordered results using `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM `HSTable` ORDER BY `score` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the order of the data in your database table should really matter because when you query the data you can sort it any which way you would like.  What is the reason why you want to have the data stored in the database in the correct order?

Answer (score 0):

That is not the correct way to select records in SQL. Use this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!